# How to disable checkbox on specific row in react-table checkboxHOC (6.8.6)

Tags: react-table, react-table-v6

I am using react-table 6.8.6, and I want to disable the checkbox on a specific row with react-table using checkboxHOC. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/883), you will have to create your own component for the checkbox. The checkbox HOC is an example and is a fairly short piece of code that was meant to be hacked.